# Как получить свойства оборудования из диспетчера устройств

Tags: c#

Делаю приложение для тестирования пк. Нужно считать устройство которое подключено к конкретному PCI порту. С помощью диспетчера устройств это можно сделать так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также в сведениях устройств можно найти такие свойства: Дети, родитель.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно получить доступ к этим параметра с помощью c#?
Пробовал через wmi - устройства нахожу, но взаимосвязь родитель/дети получить не могу.
Также пробовал через реестр, там просто нет свойства ParentIdPrefix у PCI порта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этих зависимостей нет в операционной системе, их по своей какой-тио внутренней логике выстраивает Диспетчер устройств.

Comment: Но, например, сам сетевой адаптер имеет также свойство родитель, и в реестре у него есть параметр ParentIdPrefix, с помощью которого можно найти  "Виртуальный адаптер Wi-Fi Direct (Майкрософт)" в WMI, значит и у PCI слота можно где-то найти зависимость родитель/дети.... только вот где

Comment: Посмотрите на строку HardwareID, у вас через \ прописана ветка девайсов. Наверное это и есть путь к устройству.

Comment: Создать свой аналог диспетчера можно при помощи функций из библиотеки `setupapi.dll` - в ней есть всё, что вам нужно.